# R: ggplot sorting variables with text + number

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to visualize this dataset with ggplot. Different quiz have different line (with different color), and the x-axis is the date.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

Date = paste0('Day', 1:20)
dt = as.data.frame(cbind(Date, 
                         matrix(rnorm(100,80,10), nrow = 20)))
colnames(dt) = c('Date', paste0('Quiz',1:5))
```

This is the graph I hope to generate:
[image]

I tried to use `gather` to reshape the dataset so that ggplot works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gdt = gather(dt, key = 'Quiz', value = 'Score', -Date) %>%
  mutate(Score = as.numeric(Score), Quiz = as.factor(Quiz))

ggplot(data = gdt, aes(x=Date, y=Score, colour = Quiz))+
  geom_line()
```

However, this doesn't work:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
>   adjust the group aesthetic?

Another important thing is, I would like the x-axis (aka Date) to order by the number in the variable name. Currently R sort the axis in the order of D1, D11, D12..., D2, D20, but I would like the normal sequence: D1, D2, D3, ...., D20. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `ggplot` this is a matter of reshaping data from wide to long, and taking care of the ordering of `factor` levels

```
library(tidyverse)
dt %>%
    gather(Quiz, Score, -Date) %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(
        Score = as.numeric(Score),
        Date = factor(Date, levels = paste0("Day", 1:20))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Date, Score, colour = Quiz, group = Quiz)) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you so much!